# Jquery click function not triggering a click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple HTML page:

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript">  </script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#test').click();
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<a id="test" href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to trigger a click event on the element called `test` on loading the page. The actual code is actually more sophisticated than that but this very basic example is not working. I checked the console log and there are no notices there.

Comment: you have to use  $('#test').trigger("click");

Comment: @Regent no it is if the OP wants to trigger the click event, the implementation of what has to be done resides on him

Comment: @ChakravarthySM take a look at [docs](http://api.jquery.com/click/#click) to see what is going on, when you call `.click()` without arguments.

Comment: @Regent, yeah, but you can use $.trigger("click") as well

Comment: @ChakravarthySM "you can use" and "you have to use" are very different phrases. All I want to say is that this will not solve the OP's issue.

Comment: okay, let OP use which is helpful for him

Comment: @Satpal partially you are right, partially I am: `$('#test').get().click();` will cause an error. `$('#test').get(0).click();` will not cause an error.

Comment: @Regent, Yep You are correct. I missed `0` in comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use to trigger the DOM element click

```
$('#test').get(0).click();
```

Use [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get), It retrieve the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object. As `.click()` will trigger the element click event handler. It will not actually click the element.

Using simple Vanialla JS

```
document.getElementById('test').click()
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/y4tnnu83/)

Answer (score 2):

The `.click()` you are triggering is correct but you are missing a click event for `'#test'`  as shown :

```
$('#test').click(function(){
  alert('here');
});
```

Now your complete jquery code is as shown :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#test').click();  //or  $('#test').trigger('click');
  $('#test').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('here');
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href'); //redirect to specified href
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

.click() doesn't actually send a click event.

What .click() does is define something that happens when you click on the element.

Answer (score 1):

Your #test link should be bound to a function, eg:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  //do something on test click
  $('#test').on("click", alert());

 //click test
  $('#test').click();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ub8unn2b/

Answer (score 0):

Here click event is triggered i.e. click event is fired on page load but you can not load href by just triggering the click event,for that you can use

window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";